# Turn on versioning for specific sub-site (aka subweb)

Tags: versioning

Turn on versioning for specific sub-site (aka subweb)

Is versioning at list level only or can it be set to a sub-site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Versioning is indeed at the list level.  It will need to be enabled for every list and library that would need it, either through the UI or via Powershell.